# SSL certificate is added recently still facing error while using request in python script

Tags: openssl, ssl-certificate, nginx-reverse-proxy, python-3.8

SSL certificate is successfully added to application UI we can see attached certificate information
The certificate is attached recently in April and also expired by next year. The same SSL certificates are attached to other environments their we are not getting any error

```
import requests
url = "https://applcation-url/api.php"

def url_checker(url):
    get = requests.get(url)
    if get.status_code == 200:
        print("url is reachable")
    else:
        print("url not reachable")

url_checker(url)
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/tv/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 700, in urlopen
    self._prepare_proxy(conn)
  File "/home/tv/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 994, in _prepare_proxy
    conn.connect()
  File "/home/tv/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 424, in connect
    tls_in_tls=tls_in_tls,
  File "/home/tv/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py", line 450, in ssl_wrap_socket
    sock, context, tls_in_tls, server_hostname=server_hostname
  File "/home/tv/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py", line 493, in _ssl_wrap_socket_impl
    return ssl_context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=server_hostname)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 407, in wrap_socket
    _context=self, _session=session)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 817, in __init__
    self.do_handshake()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 1077, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 689, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:852)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/tv/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 450, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "/home/tv/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 786, in urlopen
    method, url, error=e, _pool=self, _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2]
  File "/home/tv/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 592, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='fossid-vs-s001.dtt.sony.co.jp', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /api.php (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:852)'),))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "vs.py", line 16, in <module>
    url_checker(url)
  File "vs.py", line 10, in url_checker
    get = requests.get(url)
  File "/home/tv/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 75, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "/home/tv/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 61, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/home/tv/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 529, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/home/tv/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 645, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/home/tv/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 517, in send
    raise SSLError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='fossid-vs-s001.dtt.sony.co.jp', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /api.php (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:852)'),))
```

ubuntu version:18
nginx version: nginx/1.14.0 (Ubuntu)
PHP : 8.1

In nginx configuration specified like below:

```
        listen 443 default_server ssl;
        ssl_certificate /home/tv/certs/certs.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /home/tv/certs/server.key;
        server_name <url>;
```

while in the get function mentioned below code but can't specify false to verify. tired to change pem file also

```
requests.get('https://website.lo', verify='/path/to/certfile')
```

while investigating the error got below print statements

```
request url: <application url>
session url:  <application url>
session script request fucntion url:  <application url>
request in session script:  <PreparedRequest [GET]>
adapters verify:  True
url/lib/python3.6 ssl hostname: <application url>
usr/lib/python3.6 ssl socket do_handshake get peername:  ('---', 10080)
usr/lib/python3.6 ssl socket do_handshake check conneccted:  None
usr/lib/python3.6 ssl do_handshake timeout:  None
usr/lib/python3.6 sslobj do handshake()
adapter exception:  [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:852)
adapter error:  <class 'urllib3.exceptions.SSLError'>
```

I don't know peer ip number should disclose or not so I specified  '--'